# Relationship using PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, join, relation

Here i have attached the error displayed in postgreSQL. Here the Book_Detail is one table and Binding_Detail is another table. Primary Key is Book_Id and Foreign Key is Binding_Id.

SELECT b.Book_Title, e.Binding_Id,
FROM Book_Details b, Binding_Details e
WHERE b.Binding_Id = e.Binding_Id;

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "FROM"
LINE 2:  FROM Book_Details b, Binding_Details e
^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 37

Comment: You did not attach anything and you should better keep avoiding this and write the necessary things as text instead.

Comment: Remove the `,` before the `FROM`. You might also want to read up on the "modern" (from '92) JOIN operator instead of using the ancient implicit joins in the WHERE clause

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your case is the comma before the FROM. You must remove this. By the way I highly recommend to do not use this syntax "FROM table a, table B", but to use JOIN instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the comma after `e.Binding_Id`

```
SELECT b.Book_Title, e.Binding_Id 
FROM Book_Details b, Binding_Details e 
WHERE b.Binding_Id = e.Binding_Id;
```

It would be better to use a JOIN

```
SELECT b.Book_Title, e.Binding_Id 
FROM Book_Details b
INNER JOIN Binding_Details e 
ON b.Binding_Id = e.Binding_Id;
```